# Alternative to Alt+Home shortcut for websites installed as apps in Chromium-based browsers

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge

In Chrome and Edge (based on Chromium), there used to be a convenient <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> shortcut to go back to the original URL from which the website was installed as an App (<kbd>...</kbd> -> <kbd>Apps</kbd> -> <kbd>install this site as an app</kbd>)  .  This shortcut was removed at some point in the past.  Is there an alternative shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such alternative shortcut to get the url of the Edge web app. If needed, you can enter `window.location.href` in the developer tools `console` to get it.

Additionally, you can advise the relevant team on this issue. Just press `Alt + Shift + i` in Edge to write your suggestion and send it.

Comment: Thanks. I sent feedback to the Edge team.  However, when I checked "window.location.href" in my app after navigating away from the original page, its value was pointing to the current page, not the original.

Comment: Well, what I mentioned above is to get the url of the current page, if you need to get the original url, you can use the script `document.referrer` in devtool console.